How to fix Git Exec Format Error from Ubuntu in WSL for Git Credential manager?
I'm running git from within WSL 2. I'm following the documentation here
and running into error
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe get: 1: /mnt/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe: Exec format error

my git config in ubuntu:
[credential "https://dev.azure.com"]
        useHttpPath = true
[credential]
        helper = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe

My git config in windows (powershell)
[credential]
        azreposCredentialType = oauth
        msauthUseBroker = true
        msauthUseDefaultAccount = true
[credential "redacted"]
        azureAuthority = [login site]
        username = [myemail]
[credential "https://dev.azure.com"]
        useHttpPath = true

What's the way to fix this?
I tried restarting WSL. It works for one or two commands and then the same error happens again.
